# node 18 not supported by angular <=14

Tags: angular

I am getting this warning while updating my node package.

> Warning: The current version of Node (18.10.0) is not supported by Angular

Any solution for this would be great help. I updated my node using the downloader file.

[image: Warning: The current version of Node (18.10.0) is not supported by Angular]

Comment: So i need to downgrade my version to 17.0.0?

Comment: I would rather downgrade to the latest even version number of node (16) since 17 reached already its end of life.

Comment: Angular v15 is scheduled to be released in the week of 2022-11-18, and it will support the new LTS = v18 version of NodeJS, you can wait till then or downgrade your NodeJS version to the previous LTS = v16.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**:

Node 18 support has landed with Angular 15.

---

[The answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45870#issuecomment-1118696409) by [Clydin](https://github.com/clydin) from the Angular team:

> Angular officially supports all Node.js versions currently in active LTS or maintenance LTS (https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#prerequisites). From the current Node.js release calendar (https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/), Node.js v18 will enter LTS on 2022-10-25. Based on the Angular release cadence, Node.js v18 would then be officially supported by Angular in v15 at the earliest. Node.js v14 will reach its end-of-life on 2023-04-30 and would then no longer be supported by Angular v16 at the earliest.

So support for Node 18 is expected for Angular 15.

For more about the supported version of node across different versions of Angular you can refer to [this table](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3).

Comment: So again, support for Node 18 is expected with Angular 15, as you said, and that is probably the case, according to the Angular release calendar (https://angular.io/guide/releases), in the week of 2022-11-18.

Comment: @Simon Yup, Angular 15 is currently in RC1 with [Node 18 support](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/623602fc3ad53e9c801fd2e63df72e6ed4ac2c34/package.json#L11).

Comment: node 16 is supoorted? is there any chart for that?

Comment: @SunilGarg You can refer to https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Comment: i bumped my project to node18... I run docker/apache in front of it to replicate production better. not sure why, but it broke my apache proxies.  wouldn't think node would effect something like that.... but it must be something with the serve flags `--host` `--public-host` or `--disable-host`.... as setting --host=0.0.0.0 make it kinda work again (hmr was broke).   The other proxy to my node api was uneffected.  So im sticking with 16 for now at least.

Comment: @nawlbergs - I've had a similar issue. My project runs just fine with node 16.x, but with 18.x, it won't load in the browser. The dev server doesn't seem to be working correctly. I use "ng serve --open=true --ssl --host=xxxx"

Comment: Till this date i am still getting above warning. shouldn't it not be appearing now?

Comment: @ammadkhan Your Angular version is likely < 15. You need v15+ for an official Node18 support.

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Just do it in your terminal before executing **ng serve** your program:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: This has helped me resolve the issue with Node 18 and Angular 12